# Spring got 400 bad request when submitting form with mapped Entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

Here is my submitting form:

```html
    <form:form action="savecustomer" method="post" modelAttribute="customer">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Name: </td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address: </td>
                <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact Number: </td>
                <td><form:input path="contactNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email Address: </td>
                <td><form:input path="emailAddress" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sex: </td>
                <td><form:input path="sex" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date Of Birth: </td>
                <td><form:input path="dateOfBirth" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employment Status: </td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="employmentStatus">
                        <form:option value="employed" label="employed"/>
                        <form:option value="unemployed" label="unemployed"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Risk Rate: </td>
                <td><form:input path="riskRate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Agent: </td>
                <td><form:select path="agent">
                    <form:options items = "${agentList}" itemValue="agent" itemLabel="firstName"/>
                </form:select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

If I try to include the "Agent" into the form for submission the error will occur.
However, it works fine when I remove it.

Here is how customer and agent are associated:

Agent:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Agent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agent")
    private List<Customer> customers;
```

Customer:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String sex;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String employmentStatus;
    private String riskRate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id")
    private Agent agent;
```

Also, the 'agent_id' is showing an error message saying that: Cannot resolve column 'agent_id'

Could someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `<form:options items = "${agentList}" itemValue="agent" itemLabel="firstName"/>` will want to use as the selection list value, the field `agent` of the object of type `Agent`. There is no such field.

I don't know enough about JPA and/or Spring's use of it to know if you use the `id` field instead, if that will just work, or if there is more to it to get the behavior you're wanting.

I'm also assuming you've correctly populated `${agentList}`, so you might want to show how you did that.

If the JSP does render, you might also grab the generated HTML and add that into your question.